# Automating Sharepoint File Repositories

Tags: sharepoint, automation

We currently have a cobbled-together file system for aggregating remote employee reports that works as follows:

- Each employee has a directory with their name on it
- Each employee's directory can only be accessed by themselves and their supervisors
- Each employee directory contains four sub-directories, labelled with the past four week starting dates
- Whenever a new week starts, a new sub-directory is created and the oldest is deleted.

I'm fairly certain that this can all be accomplished with Sharepoint *BUT* I have zero experience working with Sharepoint, so I don't even know what questions to ask in order for Google-fu to work properly. Would anybody be able to point me in the right direction to start building out this project?

Comment: SharePoint can't just add folders. You need workflows to do that. SharePoint Designer for on premises SharePoint and Power Automate for SharePoint online. -- What happens to the files in the folders? All deleted? That's a weird way to keep records.

Comment: It's not a record-keeping system, it's just for remote employees to send in. The supervisors that work in our central office take the reports and place them on our file server.